# How to automatically assign XML data based on WSDL

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am currently working on a framework regarding SOAP webservices in php, and im looking to make a system which automatically tries to create and assign the XML given a WSDL document. I am using the native php library for the soap services.

The webservices which I work with all have many of the same XML fields, but with different names.(Email/e-mail, password/pw, etc)
My code today looks like this:

```
$data = array(
    "Person" => array(
        "pw" => "123",
        "username" => "foo",
        "email" => "foo@foo.com"
    )
)
```

I would like to replace this code with a regex based wsdl parser type of function that would search the wsdl for all the "standard" fields, and then automatically fill them for me, and return the half completed data array which I then later manually fill out. The idea behind this is to save time every time a new webservice function is added, and to prevent errors whenever an existing webservice-partner in our system changes their data-variables from forexample email to e-mail. It happens more than you would believe.

Now, would this idea be stupid with to much overhead regarding the regex function, and then in the end actually prove to be more work than to simply map every single xml namespace manually? And does there exist any functions for what im thinking of already? Like DoesThisVariableFitSomewhereInThisXML(value, namespace, wsdl)?

Comment: Your idea is not stupid at all, however as WSDL is XML I suggest an XML parser instead of a regex parser. Next to that, what is your concrete programming question?

Comment: When I get a new webservice client, I want to skip the manual mapping.
So instead of manually mapping the data according to the WSDL, I would like a function to do it for me.
The function will use the array seen in the original question I asked, and fill out an XML schema and return it for me.
So if I send the array in to the function, I will get the following XML schema returned:

<Person>
 <pw>123</pw>
 <username>foo</username>
 <email>foo@foo.com</email>
</Person>
And the code also checks that these variables is in the WSDL file aswell